# Using Aurelia, update a bound property in one class from another class

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Question:  I have two classes and want to update a variable in the View of one class by calling a class from another class.  Let me elaborate.

### thisClass.js:

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {OtherClass} from "/otherClass";

@inject(OtherClass)
export class ThisClass {
    constructor(otherClass){
        this.otherClass = otherClass;
    }

    callLoader(){
        this.message = "Hi There!";
        this.otherClass.changeMessage(this.message);
    }
}
```

### otherClass.js:

```
export class OtherClass {
    constructor(){
        this.oldMessage = "";
    }

    activate(){
        this.oldMessage = "Yo!";
    }

    changeMessage(message){
        this.oldMessage = message;
    }
}
```

### otherClass.html

```
<template>
    ${oldMessage}
</template>
```

I know the new message is being brought over because when I do a console.log in changeMessage for the passed in message I can see it but the View isn't updating with the new message.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you inject `otherClass`, aurelia creates a singleton for you, but it is not the one with view created by templating engine.

One of the options for you could be pubsub messaging using aurelia-event-aggregator https://stackoverflow.com/a/32207501/3436921

Also if you have smth like:

```
<my-component ref="myComp"></my-component>
```

You can call myComp.au.controller.myCompMethod(), but as for me, it is NOT good pattern, if you need to pass the data it's better to use bindings.

EDITED: Here is example that shows two ways of communication between components, pubsub messaging and function-call handling.http://plnkr.co/edit/DuDO87wAsgM9QjtGBb9J

Comment: This is kind of new to me and I've done google searches for a proper explanation of aurelia-event-aggregator and the option you stated of using pub/sub but aside from finding some non-descriptive sites I have no idea what these things are as I am still learning Aurelia.  Do you have a site you can point me to with a more definite explanation?

Comment: try to read articles at http://www.danyow.net/ and http://blog.durandal.io/ also you can get help and search some code examples at https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss

Comment: also you can create plunker example with aurelia (http://bit.ly/aurelia-plunker) so it will be easier to define the best solution you need

Comment: You provided a solution yesterday on the aurelia discuss forum for me but I still don't understand.  I tried your example on my code.  The only difference is that I have folders by feature instead of everything together.  I get an unhandled promise rejection Error when I use lines 7 and 9on the "=" sign in your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DuDO87wAsgM9QjtGBb9J?p=preview

Comment: Can you provide the link to the plunker with exception?

Comment: Looks like you have assignment statement in the wrong place of the code, some kind of syntax error